# Honda Civic 2002 Coolant sprinkles back from Rad cap

Tags: honda, civic, coolant, cooling-system, pressure

I am having issues with this car, so I am reaching out to masses out there who could share some of their wisdom to help me understand the actual issue with this car. It has 262K miles on it.

Issue is that The Coolant sprinkles back from Rad cap while I test drive car to work for 20 mins on Highways at 75/80 MPH Speed @ 2500+ RPM. If I am driving it at less than 2500 RPM then there is not much issue but other wise it sprinkles under pressure and then I have to refill the coolant every 7-10 days which should not be the case.

[I looked at this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12272/the-mysterious-overheating-honda-civic) to see which symptoms would match in my case. I don't find anything specific there.

I showed it to the mechanic & he asked me to replace the radiator and hoses, which I did, expecting that the problem would get resolved. It still remain as it was. So far, I have already spent close to 750 $ on this car and the mechanic keeps on saying to try fixing something else with a "hope" that it might solve the problem. I love the car and want to keep it for another 50K miles at least.

What could be the reason for the car to behave such a way?

EDIT:

1. I don't see any milky solution in the engine oil.
2. I don't see any sweet smell in the exhaust.
3. There is no chocolate color oil mixing into the reservoir tank.
4. But, when the coolant sprinkles out back from the Rad Cap on to the Hot        Engine and other parts, It generates white fumes/smoke which bothers me because I am loosing coolant, and I have to refill every week or so.

There is a normal oil leak from the engine as it is a high milage car.

Please help me understand the reason of the problem and the possible price range for repairs.

Comment: can you define 'sprinkles' please?  Do you mean a fine mist or spray?

Comment: Is the coolant sprinkling from the [coolant reservior](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/25605/12030) (plastic) or is it coming from the metal cap on the radiator itself?  Was the thermostat replaced?  Does the car report a normal engine temperature?

Comment: @ DucatiKiller - Yes by sprinkles, I mean it sprays. sometimes i find the droplets under the hood also. @ JPhi1618 - Yes it is coming from the metal cap on the Radiator itself. I have not replaced the thermostat, i am the 3rd owner of car and have driven it since 2012 Oct until now and I dont know if previous owners replaced it or not. Yes, like I said, if the coolant level goes down (due to leaking out from rad cap) and if I keep driving, then it over heats. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Was the radiator cap replaced? Was the cap pressure tested? Can you replicate this while revving the engine in park?

Comment: Can you discuss the engine oil leak more? Is it like drips or puddles of oil?

Comment: @ mr_tuner . Sure, the leaks are minor leaks from the gasket between the head and body of the engine. it is not like the puddle or dripping of oil. the oil stays in for around 4-6 months time. I never had to top off the oil to meet the required level between two oil change services. I get oil change done every 3K-4K miles (~ every 3/4 months).

Comment: Are the coolant hoses unusually hard? Is there bubbling in your coolant reservoir if you have it open while starting the car?

Comment: @ I have no idea what I'm doing.   

////  Yes, I can see some bubbles coming out of the radiator cap at a regular interval. So to Say about 1/2 bubbles / minute. I have not noticed the reservoir tank for bubbles, but will do so and keep you updated.

Comment: Hello folks, i am near to the conclusion that my car is having Backpressure or bubbling in the radiator. i was looking on the internet and i found that this product Steel Seal, (https://www.steelseal.com/). claims to fix the issue. would anyone share their wisdom/experience about it. i am having mixed feeling for it. definatately want to get the car fixed, but worried it not to get overdamaged.